# window.location.replace keep reloading the page, how to stop that?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a script that change CSS at some break-points and at 2 exact points it redirect to another page.

Changing the CSS work smoothly, but the redirect points, script keep reloading the page forever, how to stop it and set it to reload only once and reload again if needed "resolution changes again."

Here is the code:

```
/*Change CSS in response to common resolutions.*/
$(document).ready(function() {
    checkWidth ();
    $(window).resize(checkWidth);
});

function checkWidth(){
    var windowWidth = $(window).width(),
        cssLocation = $('link[href$="main.css"]');

    if (windowWidth <= 240){
        cssLocation.attr('href','stylesheets/240-main.css');
        }
    else if (windowWidth <= 480){
        /*Redirecting point 1*/
        window.location.replace("smartPhone-index.html");
        cssLocation.attr('href','stylesheets/480-main.css');
        }       
    else if (windowWidth <= 768){
        /*Redirecting point 2*/
        window.location.replace("index.html");
        cssLocation.attr('href','stylesheets/768-main.css');
        }       
    else if (windowWidth <= 1024){
        cssLocation.attr('href','stylesheets/1024-main.css');
        }       
    else if (windowWidth >= 1280){
        cssLocation.attr('href','stylesheets/1280-main.css');
        };  
    };
```

Comment: What is this trying to achieve? Changing the href of the CSS file will not cause the CSS to reload, and I don't think a resize event does either.

Comment: You'd need to throttle your `$(window).resize()` event by the looks of it - there are a few [jQuery plugins](https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+throttle+debounce) that can help you with this.

Comment: A far better idea is to code your CSS so that it resizes for all systems. Take a look at [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com) for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid `refreshing` the page multiple times by checking the `target page name` with the `current page name`.

```
var xFullPath = window.location.pathname;
var xPageName = xFullPath.substring(xFullPath.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);

function checkWidth(){
    var windowWidth = $(window).width(),
        cssLocation = $('link[href$="main.css"]');

    if (windowWidth <= 240){
        cssLocation.attr('href','stylesheets/240-main.css');
        }
    else if (windowWidth <= 480){
        /*Redirecting point 1*/
        if (xPageName !== "smartPhone-index.html")
        {
        window.location.replace("smartPhone-index.html");
        cssLocation.attr('href','stylesheets/480-main.css');
        }

        }       
    else if (windowWidth <= 768){
        /*Redirecting point 2*/
        if (xPageName !== "index.html")
         {
           window.location.replace("index.html");
           cssLocation.attr('href','stylesheets/768-main.css');
         }
      }       
    else if (windowWidth <= 1024){
        cssLocation.attr('href','stylesheets/1024-main.css');
        }       
    else if (windowWidth >= 1280){
        cssLocation.attr('href','stylesheets/1280-main.css');
        };  
    };
```

Comment: Yet I had to pull out the cssLocation.attr out of the 2nd if to make it work perfectly.
You are brilliant!!
Thank you allot!!

Answer (score 1):

Don't use javascript for this, use [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries).

Directly in the link tag:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width: 240px)" href="stylesheets/240-main.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width: 241px) and (max-width: 480px)" href="stylesheets/480-main.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 768px)" href="stylesheets/768-main.css" />
<!-- etc... -->
```

Or directly in the CSS:

```
@import url(stylesheets/240-main.css) (max-width:240px);
@import url(stylesheets/480-main.css) (min-width:241px) and (max-width:480px);
@import url(stylesheets/768-main.css) (min-width:481px) and (max-width:768px);
/* etc... */
```

The browser will auto-load/change the stylesheet, on page load and during window resizing.